# UIPickerView Column Offset

Tags: ios, swift, alignment, uipickerview, offset

I have a UIPickerView with 2 columns for a simple timer application. The two columns are for minutes and seconds. It works perfectly fine except that the right column is not aligned correctly as seen here:

[image]

I did change the `widthForComponent` to half of the `screenBounds.width` which improved the issue a bit but still, the right column is slightly closer to the screen's brink than the left.

Is there a way to change that and make it look nicer? 
Thanks in advance :)